# display component across all paths except some in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm attempting to create a few routes on my web app using `react-router`. However, some pages need to share components - such as the `Navigation` or `Footer` - where others do not.

What I essentially need is a way to check if a path *doesn't* match a few preset locations, and if it doesn't then render the content.

At the moment I'm doing this like so:

```
const displayComponentIfAllowed = (location, component) => {
    const C = component;
    const globalComponentsDisallowedPaths = ["/booking"];

    // If the path matches something within the blocked list, then return null.
    let allowToRender = true;
    globalComponentsDisallowedPaths.forEach(disallowedPath => {
        if(location.pathname === disallowedPath){
            allowToRender = false;
        }
    });

    // Otherwise, return component to render.
    return allowToRender ? <C /> : null;
}

return (
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route render={({ location }) => displayComponentIfAllowed(location, Navigation)} />
            <Route path="/">
                <Route index element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="booking/:customer_id" element={<Booking />} />
            </Route>
            <Route render={({ location }) => displayComponentIfAllowed(location, Footer)} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
);
```

However, ever since **V6** of `react-router-dom` has been introduced, this doesn't seem to work. I imagine this is because the `render` prop has been deprecated (although I'm unsure, but there's no mention of it in the docs).

Are there any workarounds - or a better implementation of this which works with **V6**? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout component that renders the UI components you want ***and*** an `Outlet` for nested routes to be rendered into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const HeaderFooterLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navigation />
    <Outlet />
    <Footer />
  </>
);
```

...

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

...

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<HeaderFooterLayout />} >
      <Route path="/">
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        ... other routes you want to render with header/footer ...
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path="booking/:customer_id" element={<Booking />} />
    ... other routes you want to not render with header/footer ...
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: Not too sure why, but when I tried this I get the error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')`. I'm not using `pathname` _anywhere_ in my code.

Comment: @GROVER. First, thanks for the edit. Second... let me test this out, it *should* be fairly correct, but I did just copy/paste from your code so something minor may've been missed.

Comment: @GROVER. Hmm, seems to run without issue here in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/display-component-across-all-paths-except-some-in-react-router-dom-v6-pknm1). I don't see any errors in the console. Are you using one of the higher-level routers, i.e. `BrowserRouter`? I think you might see that error if you use the low-level [`Router`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router) and don't pass the required props, `location` and `navigator`. It's advised to use the higher-level routers unless you've a compelling need to customize.

Comment: I'm using `BrowserRouter` as `Router`. Bit strange :(

Comment: @GROVER. Yes, weird indeed. Try killing/restarting any code watchers/hot-reloaders, if that doens't work, uninstall/reinstall `react-router-dom`. If issue persists can you post the error message and stacktrace to your question?